# Cakephp conditions on has many

Tags: cakephp

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I did not really know how to search for what I want. Consequently I did not find the answer.

So I'm using cakephp and I have a model called 'sponsor' which has many 'banners', 'activities' and 'vacancies'.

In the controller I now have:

```
public function index()
{
$this->_setRedesign();
$sponsors = $this->Sponsor->find('all', [
  'order'      => [
    'Sponsor.name',
  ],
  'conditions' => [
    'publish_from <'    => date('Y-m-d'),
    'publish_to >'    => date('Y-m-d'),
  ],
]);
$this->set(compact('sponsors'));
}
```

If I check the variable $sponsors in the cakephp debug, I see for $sponsor:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nVYZ.jpg

This is in principle how I want the $sponsors to look like, but what I want is conditioning on the activities for example. So that, for example, sponsor number 1 only has the activities that are in the future (so not all 3 but only 2). Of course I can loop over all the activities of a sponsor in the view and only do something with the ones that are in the future. But I was wondering if there is a controller solution.

Edit:
To clarify: I do want all the sponsors (not only the sponsors that have activities in the future), but from one sponsor I only want the activities that take place in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Using the Containablebehavior.

With my code looking like this, I achieved what I wanted:

```
$sponsors = $this->Sponsor->find('all', [
        'order'      => [
            'Sponsor.name',
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            'publish_from <'    => date('Y-m-d'),
            'publish_to >'    => date('Y-m-d'),
        ],
        'contain' => [
            'Activity' => [
                'conditions' => [
                    'Activity.time_start >'  => date('Y-m-d')
                ]
            ]   
        ]
    ]);
```